# Values of the infinite product $\prod_n\frac{(n+1)x}{1+nx}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, infinite-product

I am trying to compute the inverval of convergence and the explicit value of the infinite series $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{(n+1)x}{1+nx}\right).$$ I believe the interval of convergence is $(-1,1)$ and exact value is $\dfrac{x}{1-x},$ but I might be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us the reasons for your conjecture? Btw, the product is surely convergent for $x=1$.

Comment: @MartinR: I was writing an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427496/how-to-develop-dfrac11-x-into-1-dfracx1x-dfrac1-cdot2x21x) and came across this.

Comment: For $x=1/2$ you have $\prod \frac{n+1}{n+2}$, which converges to zero.

Comment: For $x=1$ obviously converges and for $x=-1$ you have a division by $0$ in the first factor. Is there a typo in your question?

Comment: @jjagmath: Thanks for mention it.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria. The convergence of $\prod a_n$ is strongly related to the convergence of $\sum \log a_n$ and that of $\sum (a_n -1)$.

Comment: @Bumblebee For $x = -1/2, -1/3, -1/4, \cdots$ you also have divisions by $0$. What exactly make you believe that the product converges in $(-1,1)$?

Comment: I don't think $x/(1-x)$ is the closed-form. For example take $x=1$.

Comment: Are you sure it converges? If we rewrite it as $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left ( 1 + \frac{x-1}{1+nx} \right ),$$ then since $x$ is constant, we can approximate it by $$\exp \left ( (x-1) \sum \frac{1}{1+nx} \right ).$$ Since $1+nx \approx nx$, we factor out the $x$ and approximate the harmonic series by a $\ln(n)$. That tells us the product should be roughly $$n^{\frac{x-1}{x}}$$ which diverges for $x \neq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For numbers of the form $-\frac{1}{n}$ the product is not defined, for the other negatives values the product diverges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$. For $x \in [0,1)$ the product diverges to $0$. For $x>1$ the product diverges to $\infty$. So the product only converges for $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have spend little more time on this :)